# How to manage concurrency in Coredata?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a multithreaded app using `coredata`.
when the app launches, there are many `cloudkit NSoperations` running simultaneously.
In each operation's completion block I am doing some core data processing.

Since the core data processing is being done in the background simultaneously by different operations, duplicate Managed Objects are being created.

I am using Coredata's background context and using `performAndWait()` method to do core data processing.

How can I solve this issue?

I thought using `performAndWait()` on background Context will ensure my background Core Data updates are all performed on one single thread. But still the duplicate Managed Objects are getting created.

As a workaround I'm using Core data's Unique attribute Constraint feature. But is this the right approach?

Comment: Are you using same managedObject in all operations?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same managedObject in all operations. In each operation I check if the managed Object exists. If it doesn't exist I'm creating the managed Object.

Comment: When you say *duplicate core data entities*, I think you mean *duplicate managed objects*.  If so, please *Edit* your post to make answering it more clear so we can give the correct answer :)

Comment: Also, please explain what you mean in your comment *creating the managed object*.  Are you using an `insert…` function?  Posting code is helpful.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question and posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this.
The right way is to use Core data background context. Use `performAndWait()` to do all core data processing tasks inside it's block.